# error in React-Native-Vector-Icons when using for Web / Server Side rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to leverage [React-native-vecor-icons package](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) in a project that uses Server-Side-Rendering react deployment (SSR).

React-native-vector-icons works fine in standard web deployments as well (not just in react-native on mobile).  HOwever with Server-side-rendering there is a problem.

The package author, [chose](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/219) to publish his library into NPM repository with ES6 syntax for modules (eg import ... }.

While web-browsers rely on transply by babel to ES5, during app build stage -- this does not help with server side deployment.  Because it is the server (NodeJs) that needs to be able to understand the package syntax.

This is, I believe, why I am getting this error.
If my understanding of the problem is correct, then I need to figure out a way to get Babel to transply this offending package on the fly and to feed it into node-js at run time.

This is where I need help, simply setting various stuff at .babelrc is not helping (see below). And I do not know how to make this work without making manual changes to the React-native-vector icons code  (See at the end the manual changes I that I figured out to make... to test out the theory).

The error:

```
c:\Users\v\home\devel\mine\ltproject\mob\rnweb\aa1a\ssr-aft\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\Ionicons.js:6
import createIconSet from './lib/create-icon-set';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:605:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons (c:\Users\v\home\devel\mine\ltproject\mob\rnweb\aa1a\ssr-aft\build\server.js:1527:18)
```

The piece of code from React Native Vector Icons library  within node_modules, that's causing the problem (first import statement)

```
/**
 * Ionicons icon set component.
 * Usage: <Ionicons name="icon-name" size={20} color="#4F8EF7" />
 */

import createIconSet from './lib/create-icon-set';
import glyphMap from './glyphmaps/Ionicons.json';

const iconSet = createIconSet(glyphMap, 'Ionicons', 'Ionicons.ttf');

export default iconSet;

export const Button = iconSet.Button;
export const TabBarItem = iconSet.TabBarItem;
export const TabBarItemIOS = iconSet.TabBarItemIOS;
export const ToolbarAndroid = iconSet.ToolbarAndroid;
export const getImageSource = iconSet.getImageSource;
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "aa1a",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "XYZ",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "razzle start",
    "build": "razzle build",
    "test": "razzle test --env=jsdom",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node build/server.js",
    "vclient": "webpack --watch --progress"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@jaredpalmer/after": "latest",
    "airbnb-browser-shims": "^2.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "compression": "^1.7.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "postcss-syntax": "^0.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "pubsub-js": "^1.6",
    "qs": "^6.5.2",
    "razzle": "^2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-art": "^16.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.0-rc.2",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.19",
    "react-virtualized-image-measurer": "^0.3",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "^1.4.0",
    "tree-model": "^1.0.6",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.7.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "stylelint": "^9.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "treeify": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

I had also tried to tell babel-loader to transply into ES5 syntax compatible with node version ( (I am running node 9.10)).  But installing babel-preset-env @1.3.3 (because that's what razzle/babel is using)). And, then, modifying my .babelrc with

```
{
    "presets": ["razzle/babel",
                "react-native",
                [
                    "babel-preset-env",
                   {
                       "targets": {
                           "node": 9,
                           "esmodules": true
                       }
                   }   
                ]
               ],
    "plugins": ["react-native-web",
                "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
                "transform-class-properties"
               ]
}
```

That, unfortunately, did not help -- getting same error.

I also tried upgrading to node **v10.2** and using

> npm start -- **--experimental-modules**
>   ... razzle  start "--experimental-modules"

Did not work either.. although I am not 100% sure if razzle, in this case is passing the command line arg into node.js

As noted, above -- I figured out **the manual code changes I need** to make to get RN vector icons to start up under Node JS (I am using version 9.1)

Change 1)   CD to node_modules/react-native-vector-icons.   Copy Ionicons.js into Ionicons_org.js.

Change 2)  Replace the Ionicons.js with this code (and delete the rest).

```
require('babel-register')({
  plugins: ["transform-class-properties","react-native-web"], 
  presets: [ 'env' ],

  // Ignore everything in node_modules except node_modules/react-native-vector-icons
  ignore: /node_modules\/(?!react-native-vector-icons)/
})

// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require('./Ionicons_org.js')
```